# Bumblebee segfault in nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I recently tried to use my laptop (an MSI GE60, with a GeForce GT 750M) under lubuntu 13.10.
From the info I gathered, I had to use Bumblebee if I wanted to use the GeForce.

I installed it using instruction found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work#36936) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee). I've updated the drivers to `nvidia-319-updates`.

But despite that, when I try to run `primusrun glxgears`, I have the following output:

```
 kernel: [  138.620890] bbswitch: enabling discrete graphics
 kernel: [  139.075668] pci 0000:01:00.0: power state changed by ACPI to D0
 kernel: [  139.085492] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20130102 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
 kernel: [  139.085499] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  319.60  Wed Sep 25 14:28:26 PDT 2013
 acpid: client 1994[0:1001] has disconnected
 acpid: client 1994[0:1001] has disconnected
 acpid: client connected from 2024[0:1001]
 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
 kernel: [  139.130099] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
 kernel: [  139.134812] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
 .
 .
 .
 kernel: [  139.609964] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
 kernel: [  139.700688] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
 acpid: client connected from 2024[0:1001]
 acpid: 1 client rule loaded
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (WW) Unresolved symbol: fbGetGCPrivateKey
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Failed to enable display hotplug notification
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initiate mode change.
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to complete mode change
 kernel: [  140.107177] glxgears[2012]: segfault at 0 ip 00007fed358ca547 sp 00007fffd5883610 error 4 in libGL.so.1[7fed358a5000+41000]
 kernel: [  140.367801] [drm] Module unloaded
 kernel: [  140.369287] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
 kernel: [  140.369298] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20130517/nsarguments-95)
 kernel: [  140.385057] pci 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D0
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) 
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) Backtrace:
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) 0: Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x3d) [0x7f4763c7902d]
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) 1: Xorg (0x7f4763ad7000+0x1a5d99) [0x7f4763c7cd99]
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f4762bd7000+0xfbb0) [0x7f4762be6bb0]
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) 3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (malloc_usable_size+0x26) [0x7f4761875326]
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) 4: /usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates/libGL.so.1 (0x7f475e981000+0xb20c4) [0x7f475ea330c4]
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) 
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x0
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) 
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) 
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) 
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.8.log" for additional information.
 bumblebeed[1209]: [XORG] (EE)
```

I tried to look at `/var/log/Xorg.8.log`, but didn't found any useful info there (I tried to look for erros but had the following result :

```
 cat /var/log/Xorg.8.log | grep EE
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
 [  1664.687] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
 [  1664.721] (EE) Failed to load module "kbd" (module does not exist, 0)
 [  1665.313] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initiate mode change.
 [  1665.313] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to complete mode change
 [  1665.678] (EE) Failed to load module "kbd" (module does not exist, 0)
 [  1665.678] (EE) No input driver matching `kbd'
 [  1665.892] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

I also tried to change the `KeepUnusedXServer` to `true` to see if I had other outputs, but the only one I had in syslog was the following: `glxgears[2086]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f5ee5d41547 sp 00007fff71783f40 error 4 in libGL.so.1[7f5ee5d1c000+41000]`.

Also on note, when I run `primusrun nvidia-settings` I have a message telling me that I'm not running the nvidia driver.
But `optirun nvidia-settings -c :8` does show the settings.Tho, it still produces the same kind of log in `syslog`.

Just in case, the (uncommented) `bumblebee.conf`:

```
 [bumblebeed]
 VirtualDisplay=:8
 KeepUnusedXServer=false
 ServerGroup=bumblebee
 TurnCardOffAtExit=false
 NoEcoModeOverride=false
 Driver=nvidia
 XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d

 [optirun]
 Bridge=auto
 VGLTransport=proxy
 PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
 AllowFallbackToIGC=false

 [driver-nvidia]
 KernelDriver=nvidia-319-updates
 PMMethod=auto
 LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-319-updates

 XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-319-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules
 XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

 [driver-nouveau]
 KernelDriver=nouveau
 PMMethod=auto
 XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

Thanks in advance for the replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it suddendly started working. I did nothing special besides update and upgrades. Dunno what fixed it.